# Cantor's diagonal argument without equality

Tags: logic, set-theory

Trevor Wilson posted an answer while I was preparing an edit to the question. I think Trevor would have given essentially the same answer to the modified question. But, to make things as clear as possible, I will leave the old version after the statement of the new one. (I will also change a few details to the old version.) (Thank you to Trevor for his answer.)

### New version of the question

Let $\mathcal T$ be the theory one gets by admitting only Axioms schema 3 (Axiom schema of specification) of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFC) --- and forbidding the (direct or indirect) use of the equal sign.

Is $\mathcal T$ consistent?

### Old version of the question

Here is one of the first exercises of Roger Godement's book *Cours d'algèbre*:

Let $A$ be a set, and let $\mathcal P(A)$ be the set of all subsets of $A$. Then the inclusion $\mathcal P(A)\subset A$ does not hold.

Of course, this follows immediately from Cantor's diagonal argument. But what I find striking is that, in this form, the diagonal argument does not involve the notion of equality. This prompts the question:

(A) Are there other interesting examples of mathematical reasonings which don't involve the notion of equality?

Take your favorite set theory and remove everything which involves, directly or indirectly, the equal sign. Let $\mathcal T$ be the resulting theory. Then one can ask:

(B) Is $\mathcal T$ complete? Is $\mathcal T$ consistent?

Here is one way to make Question (B) precise. Take Bourbaki's set theory, and drop:

- the equal sign,
- Axiom Schemata S6 and S7,
- Axioms A1, A2, A3 and A4.

For the sake of completeness, let's spell out Cantor's diagonal argument (in the present setting): Assume by contradiction
$$
X\subset A\quad\implies\quad X\in A,
$$
let $B$ be a set such that 
$$
X\in B\quad\iff\quad X\in A\text{ and }X\notin X,
$$
and observe 
$$
B\in B\quad\iff\quad B\notin B.
$$
[We could not have said "let $B$ be *the* set such that ...", because this would have involved an implicit use of the notion of equality --- more precisely: of Axiom 1 of extensionality.]

Comment: Assuming that ZFC is consistent, any of its sub-theories (such as the one you ask about in the new question, $\mathcal{T}$) must also be consistent.  Are you wondering whether $\mathcal{T}$ has strictly lower consistency strength than ZFC, _i.e._ whether ZFC proves $\mathcal{T}$ to be consistent?

Comment: Dear Trevor: I also agree with your first sentence. I'm not wondering whether ZFC proves $\mathcal T$ to be consistent. Do you agree that the consistency of $\mathcal T$ can be translated into a combinatorial statement (in term of free monoids)? If you do, then you can ask whether this statement can be proved (like any statement about monoids).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything about the theory of monoids.  But notice that $\{\emptyset\}$ is a model of your theory $\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: ...and $\emptyset$ would also be a model if our logic allowed empty models.

Comment: The notion of monoid is not crucial here. The point is: Do you agree that the consistency of $\mathcal T$ can be translated into a combinatorial statement, or, if you prefer, into a standard mathematical statement?

Comment: Is the statement that $\{\emptyset\}$ is a model of the theory combinatorial enough?  It seems pretty combinatorial to me.  If you get rid of so many axioms (_e.g._ pairing, union, infinity, _etc._) your theory will have some very simple models.

Comment: I'm sure you know much more than I about models. It seems to me that, according to Cohen, the notion of model involves that of equality. Anyway, in theory $\mathcal T$ (with specification only), we have infinitely many distinct terms, but no notion of object. And, again, the statement $\mathcal P(A)\not\subset A$ (suitably translated) holds in $\mathcal T$.

Comment: The notions of "monoid" and "combinatorics" probably involve some notion of equality also.  Do you want to banish equality from the meta-language also?  You could probably do that along the same lines as in my answer, but I'm not sure I see the point.  Surely we are allowed to use accepted logical notions when reasoning about the consistency of a theory?

Comment: I fully agree. My question is: Can one prove that $\mathcal T$ is consistent using (in our meta-language) accepted logical notions? ($\mathcal T$ being again the theory with specification and no other axiom.)

Comment: My answer is: Yes, by exhibiting a model (namely $\emptyset$, $\{\emptyset\}$, or more generally the rank initial segment $V_n$ of $V$ where $n$ is a natural number.)

Comment: Are you sure you're not assuming the consistency of ZF?

Comment: Yes, this time I am sure.  You can write down a complete description of the structure, say, $V_3$, and check that it satisfies the axiom schema of specification.  No (non-naive) set theory is involved, just finitary reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

If we consider ZFC as a theory in first-order logic without equality (that is, we remove the non-logical axioms mentioning equality) then the Axiom of Extensionality, which says that two sets are equal if and only if they have the same elements, can be considered as a *definition* of equality.  Then we can rewrite every axiom and every theorem to avoid mentioning equality by replacing every occurrence of "$x = y$" in the logical and non-logical axioms with "$\forall z\,(z \in x \iff z \in y)$" (replacing $x$, $y$, and $z$ with appropriate variable names.)  The resulting theory is essentially the same as ZFC.  In particular, they are not complete, and seem so far to be consistent.

I don't know if this meets your criterion of not *indirectly* involving equality, because there may be some theorems that are hard to understand without putting them back in terms of equality (which is now a defined notion.)  However this may just be because we are used to seeing them stated in this manner, and in any case the judgement seems subjective.

Comment: Dear Trevor: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't understand it. Here are two questions: (1) I think an inconsistent theory is complete. Do you agree with this? (2) How do you define the cardinal number 0 without the Axiom of extensionality?

Comment: You are correct that an inconsistent theory is complete (at least my definition says it is also.)  So I should have said that if it is consistent, then it is incomplete.  (Sometimes I tacitly assume that ZFC, inaccessible cardinals, _etc._ are consistent.)  For your second question, note that without equality we cannot define _objects_ at all, only _predicates_.  We cannot prove that any predicate defines a unique object, because there is no longer any notion of uniqueness.  So all we can do is define a "zero-ness" predicate $\varphi(x)$ that says $\neg \exists y\,(y\in x)$.

Comment: Dear Trevor: I'm happy to see that we agree on the first point. I dropped the completeness aspect in the new version. It was a bad idea of mine to talk about completeness. I also agree with the phrase: "without equality we cannot define objects at all". That's precisely my point! Do you agree that, without equality, we can still prove $\mathcal P(A)\not\subset A$?

Comment: Yes, we can still _prove_ anything we could prove before, provided that we first rewrite it by substituting "$\forall z\, (z \in x \iff z \in y)$" for "$x=y$".  We just can't _define_ objects in the same way, because there is no way to tell whether a definition picks out a unique object (whatever that would mean.)

Comment: How do you state and prove $0=0$ (or $0\not=1$) in $\mathcal T$?

Comment: You can't, because it is not written in the language of $\mathcal{T}$.  But you can rewrite it to say "if $x$ is zero-like and $y$ is one-like then either $x$ has an element $y$ lacks or vice-versa" where "$x$ is zero-like" means that $x$ is empty and "$y$ is one-like" means that its elements are exactly the zero-like sets.

Comment: Recall that $\mathcal T$ assumes only a single Axiom schema: that of specification. Are you saying that the other axioms of ZF are provable in $\mathcal T$?

Comment: Oh, sorry!  I was thinking about the theory I defined in my answer instead.

Comment: However it still seems to be true that one can prove the translated version "if x is zero-like and y is one-like then either x has an element y lacks or vice-versa" even in $\mathcal{T}$ (assuming we still have all the axioms of first-order logic without equality.)

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the idea that I was saying that specification implies all the other axioms.  This is certainly false.

Comment: In fact you don't need any non-logical axioms to prove the translated version of $0=1$.  But you do need some non-logical axioms to prove that zero-like and one-like objects actually exist.

Comment: Do you agree that one cannot exclude *a priori* the possibility that $\mathcal T$ is consistent, while ZF is not?

Comment: ZF is not what?

Comment: ... consistent.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that one cannot exclude this _a priori_.  This is because the consistency strength of ZF is strictly greater than that of the specification axiom scheme alone.